# Getting children of component in ExtJS 3.3.3

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I'm puzzled as to how to get the children of a component in ExtJS 3.3.3. I can currently fetch my component this way:

```
var comp = this.getComponent('test');
```

This component contains a bunch of div children. I've looked through the documentation for the component object and I can't find anything: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Component . In more recent versions, I can use ComponentQuery, but it's just not present in 3.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot.

I can just fetch it with this and then turn it back into an element this way:

```
var test = Ext.DomQuery.select('.test');
test = Ext.get(test); // Turns it back into an Ext element instead of dom.
var parent = test.parent();
```